# Which major sites block Tails and Tor visitors from creating user accounts?

Tags: tails, browsers, blocked-services, blocked

This documentation discusses how networks can fingerprint a user who's using Tails OS

- https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/fingerprint/index.en.html

There's plenty of write-ups on how Tails and Tor users are blocked from browsing some sites, but for those that can be browsed, do any major sites block Tails or Tor users from creating accounts?

By major sites I mean social media sites and internet services. To have full coverage for this question, an answer can include the niches of one or more of the following sites:

- Youtube
- Instagram
- Onlyfans
- free e-mail providers
- domain name registrars

Comment: This is a list question.  StackExchange doesn't work well with list questions as there is no definitive right answer.

Comment: as said, your answer can choose to focus on a specific internet niche (social media providers, e-mail providers, domain name registrars)